# Pass value pointed by non-const iterator by reference c++

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, set

I have an  `std::set<MyType>` container which I'm getting by get function of some class, i.e. I have somethig like this:

> ```
> typedef std::set<MyType, compareMyType> MyTypeSet;  
> // this a singleton class
> class MyClass {  
> ...  
> public:  
>     MyTypeSet& getMySet() { return mySet_; }  
> ...  
> private:  
> MyTypeSet mySet_;  
> ...  
> }
> ```

Then in other place I'm using this container:

```
MyClass obj;
MyTypeSet& mySet = mtyObj->getMySet();
MyTypeSet::iterator itBeg = mySet.begin();
// Then I'm trying to call f function
f(*itBeg);
```

Where f function has signature like below:

```
void f(MyType& param);
```

I'm getting compilation error like this:

```
note: candidates are: void f(MyType&)
error: no matching function for call to f(const MyType&)
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is mtyObj a pointer to a const object?

Comment: No, it's not a const, @Pradhan.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing details about your environment, I'm guessing your system's implementation of `set` attempts to be "safe" by aliasing `iterator` to be `const_iterator` (so that you don't try to modify set items via the iterator, which is dangerous because it might change the sort order). See [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/Cuj/01.SetIterators/SetIterators.html) for more about this.

If so, then the easiest fix is just to change the signature of your function to be `void f(const MyType& param)` as the compiler suggests.  If you *do really* need to modify the parameter (in such a way that it will not change the sort order), there are a variety of hacks to get around the `const` restriction (including using `const_cast` or the solution suggested at the above link), but I would recommend proceeding with caution.

Comment: Thanks, @Turix, I really need to modify `param` value in `f` function, so, maybe I'll use `const_cast`.

Comment: @Heghine, as the link in Turix's answer shows, it is usually a bad idea to modify the value of an element in a set, since it could break the set invariant. If you are sure that the modifications you make to param will not affect the ordering, perhaps you could simply make that part mutable and leave the function signature const?

Comment: @Pradhan, do you mean in `MyClass`? I think the problem isn't there.
The problem is in `f` function signature/call.

Comment: @Heghine I meant `MyType`. You said that you need to modify `param` in `f`. The reason `set::begin` ends up returning a `const` is that modifying a value which is already inserted in the `set` could break the invariant being maintained by its data-structure(red-black tree, iirc). However, if the modifications to `param` that would be made by `f` will not affect `param`s position in the `set`, you could make the relevant parts of `MyType` mutable, and still pass `param` in by `const` reference. This will ensure that a future revision of `f` won't accidentally break the `set`.

Comment: @Pradhan, thanks for clarification. I've tried your suggestion and it's worked!!! I think this is better way than using `const_cast`.